# ThreeJS, Ionic, Angular2+ - How to modify position BufferGeometry / BufferAttribute values - It says Index Signature ArrayLike<number> is read only

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, three.js, buffer-geometry

I have everything for a 3d implementation with Three.js working in a plain js app.  I am using BufferGeometry for lines and meshes and I am modifying the position attribute to modify their shapes.

Now I am using Ionic and converting the 3d stuff to be inside an angular component.  I have everything working except I am unable to update the position values in the bufferAttribute.

I was using this in the original js to get positions array to modify:

```
var vrts = myMesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
```

Then I could modify and set the vrts array values with things like:

```
vrts[0] = newValue;
```

and I was then setting needsUpdate = true with:

```
myMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Everything was working fine in the js app.

In the Ionic app, when I tried to point to get positions array it said: 
    Property 'attributes' does not exist on type BufferGeometry | Geometry
so I converted to this:

```
vrts = (this.geometry.getAttribute("position"));
```

and now I can access the values with:

```
vertexValue = vrts.array[0];
```

But, when I try to modify the value, ie:

```
vrts.array[0] = newValue;
```

It says:
    error TS2542: Index signature in type 'ArrayLike< number>' only permits reading

and won't allow me to modify the value.

I also had some trouble accessing the needsUpdate variable.  I was previously using:

```
myMesh.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

and have now converted to this, but not sure if it is correct:

```
(<THREE.BufferAttribute>vrts).needsUpdate = true;
```

I am also trying to set the 'positions' array to be dynamic with the following statement:

```
(<THREE.BufferAttribute>this._geometry.getAttribute("position")).setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);
```

I am using BufferGeometry for lines and meshes.  Maybe my alternative is to create a new positions array and use setAttribute('position', newPositions) each time I modify things, but it seems like this would defeat the purpose of efficient memory use by allocating new memory every time things are changed.

Thank you for your advice!